# Erlang simple_one_for_one supervisor does not restart child

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor, fault-tolerance

I have a test module and a simple_one_for_one supervisor.

test.erl

```
-module(test).

-export([
    run/1,
    do_job/1
]).

run(Fun) ->
    test_sup:start_child([Fun]).


do_job(Fun) ->
    Pid = spawn(Fun),
    io:format("started ~p~n", [Pid]),
    {ok, Pid}.
```

test_sup.erl

```
-module(test_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1]).
-export([start_child/1]).

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).


init(_Args) ->
    SupFlags = #{strategy => simple_one_for_one, intensity => 2, period => 20},

    ChildSpecs = [#{id => test,
                    start => {test, do_job, []},
                    restart => permanent,
                    shutdown => brutal_kill,
                    type => worker,
                    modules => [test]}],

    {ok, {SupFlags, ChildSpecs}}.


start_child(Args) ->
    supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, Args).
```

I start supervisor in shell by command `test_sup:start_link()`. After that i run this command: `test:run(fun() -> erlang:throw(err) end).` I except the function `do_job` restart 2times but it never does. What is the problem?

Here is shell:

```
1> test_sup:start_link().
{ok,<0.36.0>}
2> test:run(fun() -> erlang:throw(err) end).
started <0.38.0>
{ok,<0.38.0>}
3> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 16-Dec-2016::22:08:41 ===
Error in process <0.38.0> with exit value:
{{nocatch,err},[{erlang,apply,2,[]}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restarting children is contrary to how `simple_one_for_one` supervisors are defined. Per the [supervisor docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html):

> Functions delete_child/2 and restart_child/2 are invalid for simple_one_for_one supervisors and return {error,simple_one_for_one} if the specified supervisor uses this restart strategy.

In other words, what you're asking for can never happen. That's because a `simple_one_for_one` is intended for dynamic children that are defined on the fly by passing in additional startup args when you request the child. Other supervisors are able to restart their children because the startup args are statically defined in the supervisor.

Basically, this type of supervisor is strictly for ensuring a tidy shutdown when you need to have a dynamic pool of workers.